# To display active and inactive instead of true or false in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I have one doubt regarding how to change the name of column from true and false to active and inactive. As the column data type is of bit. Below is the code and I am displaying the record in web grid using repository.

```
grid.Column("IsDeleted",header: "Deleted",canSort:false)
```

Please help.

Comment: You can create a `DisplayTemplate` for typeof `bool`

Comment: can you give me sample code. i m sorry i am very much new to MVC

Comment: Start by looking at [this article](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2011/11/22/using-templates-to-display-boolean-values-as-yes-no-options.aspx)

Comment: What type of grid are you using ?

Comment: @JamesDev im using Web Grid

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have followed the article and done the same by creating View and provided the annotation to my variable by using UIHint, but still didnt get Active and Inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grid.Column(header: "Deleted",  
            format: item =>
            {
                return item.IsDeleted ? "In-Active" : "Active";
            })
```

Comment: i guess it is not applicable in MVC